# Django import adding Many-to-Many relationship based on value non-model field

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm using django-import-export to import an xls.

In the xls is a boolean field `is_senior` which is not a model field.

In the model I have a Many-to-Many relationship to a Model `Level` which has junior, senior etc.

If `is_senior is True` I want to:

```
senior = Level.objects.filter(name__icontains = 'senior').first()
instance.level.add(senior)
```

But the problem is:
`before_import_row` knows the non-model field, but can't add m2m relationships
`after_save_instance` doesn't have the non-model field

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set temporary attributes on the Resource instance:

```py
    def before_import_row(self, row, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        self.is_senior = row.get("is_senior")


    def after_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
        print(self.is_senior)
```

This will work as long as rows, are not skipped for any reason (`skip_row()` is defined or in case of errors).  Test thoroughly to ensure that `is_senior` is set correctly.